# Accessing C# library from VC++ code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++

I have windows form application written in VC ++ . I want to change the button click in this app (WInform app in VC++) to hit a function written in C#.
What are the possible ways to do this.

Comment: Is this a CLI project or straight Win32/MFC?

Comment: This is a straight Win32/MFC project

Comment: If this really is necessary, can you just compile the C# as an executable and call that?  C++ to C# is a lot more difficult than the other way around.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/ijw_unmanaged.aspx

Comment: Is the C# function part of an existing library or something you are writing ?

Comment: Its a new library i am building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a C# assembly without compiling with C++/CLI is tricky. some of the ideas I've had:

a) Create a mixed-assembly wrapper dll (mixed assemblies contain both native code and managed code). Add a reference to your C# assembly, then create functions in your dll that call the C# code via C++/CLI, then define dll entrypoints ( __declspec(dllexport) ) for those functions. You can now link against the dll as it will provide a native interface that C++ can understand, while internally that dll can call your C# code.
( Afterthought: You can probably compile this to a .lib, that would be easier than a dll.)

[Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Static Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

b) Use Mono to call the C# assembly. Mono has a C API which you can use to load and use managed assemblies without using c++/CLI. This is what I would do if C++/CLI is not an option.

[Embedding Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono)

c) If your function has a relatively simple input/output signature (no large objects, etc) you might consider compiling your C# function into an executable and use standard input/output to call the function. You'll have to carry input arguments and the output as text, though. Then make C++ start the executable and pass some input to it, and read the output.